# Normalize a negative range

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I convert a range of -12  to 12  as a value between 0 and 1 ?

I'm guessing this is a relatively simple problem, I just can't figure it out.

```
float value=[valuestring floatValue];
            float  absval =fabsf(value);
            if (value<0) {
                //0-0.5
                value=(absval/12);
                value=value*.5;

                value-=.5;



            }else if (value>0)
            {
                //0.5-1
                value=(absval/12);
                value=value*.5;
                value+=.5;
            }else if(value==0)
            {

                //0.5
                value=0.5;


            }
```

Comment: If $-12\leq x\leq 12$ then $u=\dfrac{x+12}{24}$ satisfy: $0\leq u\leq 1$

Comment: @HebertodelRio, have you noticed my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $$-12\le x\le 12$$

Note that we need to change the range difference from $12-(-12)=24,$ to $1-0=1$

So, dividing throughout by $24,$

$$-\frac12\le \frac x{24}\le \frac12$$

Now, we need to shift  by $\frac12$

$$0\le \frac12+ \frac x{24}\le 1$$

So, if we put $$y=\frac12+ \frac x{24}=\frac{12+x}{24}, -1\le y\le1$$

Comment: thankyou for the detailed explanation

Comment: @dubbeat, my pleasure